# strange connect errors appearing in GCP GCE logs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloudflare

I have a Nodejs 12 app running in Google Cloud Platform on a GCE VM.  As of yesterday my uncaught exception handler (`process.on('uncaughtException', (e) => {`) started logging some errors that I don't recognize:

```
"uncaughtException",{
    "stack":"Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.19.213.87:10442 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16)",
    "message":"connect ETIMEDOUT 104.19.213.87:10442",
    "errno":"ETIMEDOUT",
    "code":"ETIMEDOUT",
    "syscall":"connect",
    "address":"104.19.213.87",
    "port":10442
}
```

Is there a way to find out what is causing the problem?

Comment: are this the messages appearing in the logs of the app or in the system logs? also is that connection part of the flow of your app?

Comment: These are application logs.  Something my app tries to connect to is failing.  But I don't have this IP address in any of my configs.

Answer (score 0):

It tells me "this site can’t be reached", whatever this web-service may be.

Check your CloudFlare and/or DNS configuration, because [`104.19.213.87`](http://104.19.213.87)`:80` (which is a Cloudflare network range) complains: `Error 1003 - Direct IP access not allowed`. Probably you might have to use a host-name instead of IP, so that CloudFlare DNS could resolve it. See [cloudflare error 1003](https://www.google.com/search?q=cloudflare+error+1003), eg. [`node-http-proxy/issues/779`](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/issues/779), which hints for `changeOrigin: true`. Besides, this [`TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect) error doesn't seem to be special.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but perhaps I wasn't clear.  I do not know where this IP address comes from.  I don't use it in any of my configuration.  Hence the question.

Comment: In your app somewhere you are using a cloudflare service, it is over there where you are using this IP, as Martin said maybe you are calling this in a URL or inside a library you are consuming.